# How to acess the result from a function pointer in dart

Tags: c++, dart, pointers, ffi, dart-ffi

I am trying to get the return value from c++ function in dart.

My c++ code is something like this

```
static bool is_alive() {
  return true;
}
```

From dart, I loaded the shared lib with this native code and I am trying to call that `is_alive()` function.

```
typedef BooleanFunction = Pointer<Int8> Function();

Pointer<NativeFunction<BooleanFunction>> isAlive = (functionAddress).cast<NativeFunction<BooleanFunction>>();
Pointer<Int8> Function() isAliveFunc = isAlive.asFunction();
```

I called then the `isAliveFunc` from dart and I want the result of that functions. I tried all these ways. None of these works.

```
Pointer<Int8> casted = isAliveFunc()!.cast();
Pointer<Int8>? fromPointer = isAliveFunc()!;

developer.log('value : $casted');
```

I get the result like this  `Pointer<Int8>: address=0x1`

How can I fetch the value from this pointer in dart ? I expect to get a 1 or 0 as the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason you never actually *call* your `isAliveFunc` function.

Just call the function as you would any other:

```dart
Pointer<Int8> casted = isAliveFunc();
```

or

```dart
Pointer<Int8> casted = isAliveFunc.call();
```

You should also be paying attention to your Dart static analysis warnings and errors.

---

Your function definitions are also incorrect. `is_alive` returns a `bool`/`Int8`, not a pointer.

Your `BooleanFunction` typedef should be:

```dart
typedef BooleanFunction = Int8 Function();

int Function() isAliveFunc = isAlive.asFunction();
```

And the function call return should be assigned to an `int`:

```dart
int casted = isAliveFunc();
```

Comment: it was a typo that the function is not getting called.

Comment: @jgm There are other problems with your code that you have not addressed and are using bang operators and other null-safe oddities left and right for some reason. You really need to be careful about typos because they make your code unreproducible.

Comment: your solution to the function definition solved the issue. Can you also tell me what should i declare in dart, if i want to return a string.

my cpp function is in that case like this 

static const char* getStringText() {
  return std::string("Hello world").c_str();;
}

functions[1] = (char **) getStringText;

Comment: @jgm You'll want a `Pointer<Utf8>`. The links in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60273020/13250142) stack overflow answer will be of some help.

Comment: both your solutions worked. One final query, how would i return from a native function in c++ which has a return type of `std::vector<std::uint8_t> ` and get the result in dart ? Is it better to convert to to string ?

Comment: @jgm I only know C, not c++. Is that return type just an array of some kind? If so, you're going to have to figure out a way to return a pointer and handle everything in a c-like manner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234730/discussion-between-jgm-and-christopher-moore).