# How to create a pointer to a dart function that takes a String in dart:ffi?

Tags: c, flutter, dart, dart-ffi

I want to create binding to this C function in dart, this C function accepts a function pointer called `progress_monitor`:

```
FFI_PLUGIN_EXPORT void* magickSetProgressMonitor(..., const void* progress_monitor,...);
```

where `progress_monitor` is a function pointer:

```
typedef bool(*MagickProgressMonitor)(const char *,const long long,
    const long long,void *);
```

In dart, I tried creating a function pointer like this:

```
typedef MagickProgressMonitor = bool Function(String text, int offset, int size, List<int>? clientData);

extension _MagickProgressMonitorExtension on MagickProgressMonitor {
  /// Creates a native function pointer from this method.
  Pointer<Void> toNativeFunctionPointer() {
    return Pointer.fromFunction<Bool Function(Pointer<Char>, LongLong, LongLong, Pointer<Void>)>(this, false).cast();
  }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
The type 'bool Function(String, int, int, List<int>?)' must be a subtype of 'Bool Function(Pointer<Char>, LongLong, LongLong, Pointer<Void>)' for 'fromFunction'.
```

I have 2 questions:

1. what types should I use with `fromFunction<???>` to remove the error?
2. the last parameter to the C function is a void* pointer which can be anything, right now I am trying to represent it as `List<int>` in dart and `unsigned char` array in C, but this doesn't seem correct, is there a way to handle this more correctly?

### Update:

I intend to use the above code by exposing an api method by something like this:

```
  void magickSetProgressMonitor(MagickProgressMonitor progressMonitor, [List<int>? clientData]) {
    final Pointer<UnsignedChar> clientDataPtr = clientData?.toUnsignedCharArray() ?? nullptr;
    final Pointer<Void> progressMonitorPtr = progressMonitor.toNativeFunctionPointer();
    Pointer<Void> oldMonitorPtr =
        _bindings.magickSetProgressMonitor(...,progressMonitorPtr,...);
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Have you seen this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61541354/dart-flutter-ffi-foreign-function-interface-native-callbacks-eg-sqlite3-exec/61550940#61550940

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "void* pointer" you can use `Pointer<Void>`.

Please see the following code for the appropriate typedefs.

```
import 'dart:ffi';

import 'package:ffi/ffi.dart';

// void* magickSetProgressMonitor(uint32_t dummy, const void* progress_monitor,...);
// we need a pair of typedefs to describe the signature on both sides
// the two typedefs will look the same if there are just pointers etc
// the differences come in parameters like integers
// this is the C signature
typedef magick_set_progress_monitor = Pointer<Void> Function(
  Uint32, // this is just here as an example to show a 32 bit unsigned
  Pointer<NativeFunction<magick_progress_monitor>>,
);
// this is the Dart signature
typedef magickSetProgressMonitor = Pointer<Void> Function(
  int, // ffi has turned the C uint type to a Dart int
  Pointer<NativeFunction<magick_progress_monitor>>,
);

void main() {
  final nativeLib = DynamicLibrary.open('mydll');
  // lookupFunction is the improved syntax for looking up functions in the lib
  // its generics are the C-style signature followed by the Dart-style
  // it returns a Function that matches the Dart-style typedef
  final mspm = nativeLib
      .lookupFunction<magick_set_progress_monitor, magickSetProgressMonitor>(
    'magickSetProgressMonitor',
  );
  
  // before calling mspm it needs the callback function, so look that up
  // this converts the Dart-style function to a pointer to a native function
  // matching the C-style typedef
  final callbackFunction = Pointer.fromFunction<magick_progress_monitor>(
    callback,
    true,
  );
  
  // and call mspm passing the (dummy, example) int and callback function
  final result = mspm(123, callbackFunction);
}

//typedef bool(*MagickProgressMonitor)(const char *,const long long,
//     const long long,void *);
// callback functions need a C-style typedef (so that FFI knows the int sizes)
typedef magick_progress_monitor = Bool Function(
  Pointer<Utf8>, // the documentation says this is a string, so use Utf8
  LongLong,
  LongLong,
  Pointer<Void>,
);

bool callback(
  Pointer<Utf8> t,
  int offset,
  int extent,
  Pointer<Void> client_data,
) {
  final text = t.toDartString(); // convert the Pointer<Utf8> to Dart string
  // do something here with the values - probably call a Dart function provided by the user
  return true;
}
```

Update following your edit and questions.

You don't have any choice about the callback. Its typedef must match exactly the C typedef that the C code expects to call. You are correct that you shouldn't be exposing `Pointer` types to your user, so you should keep the callback function in your code, convert the reason string there, then call your user's function with a Dart String.

Finally, it's also clear that this will never work. This is, as its name suggests, a callback function that is called off the main Dart thread by some background process. The C->Dart callback functionality is restricted to callbacks that are made immediately as part of a Dart->C->Dart call.

Comment: I don't understand the answer very much, what is the difference between `example_foo ` and `ExampleFoo `, they seem to have the exact same definition? Please can you use some more informative names, I am already confused with all these generic types that feel like magic

Comment: And also why did you put `Pointer<Int8>` in the dart function `callback` ? These ffi types are not meant to be exposed in this function as I want it to be provided by the user

Comment: `For "void* pointer" you can use Pointer<Void>` I am not asking about this, I am asking about the dart equivalent of `Pointer<Void>`, the C function accepts `void*` which can be any data. what is the equivalent of this in dart?

Comment: I updated the question to make it clear how it is intended to be used

Comment: Before I update the answer, be very suspicious of functions that have names like `ProgressMonitor`. Are these called on a background thread? If so, it won't work as you may not call from C->Dart on anything but the main Dart thread. (In other words, callbacks must be synchronous as in they must be called immediately Dart->C->Dart.

Comment: they will not be invoked in the `C` function (Dart -> `C` -> Dart) immediately, they will be invoked later (after the C function returns), so ig you mean this function cannot have a binding in dart? If this is the case, anyway please  can you update the answer to show how to create binding for a dart function that accepts a string as above (supposing it will be called immediately in the C invokation)?

Comment: I'll update, but look at this answer for converting String to Pointer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60270263/how-to-map-dart-string-with-ffi

Comment: To answer the other question, no you can't use it if it happens later. So you can devise an alternative of having the C function update some (C) state with the latest progress and then you can poll from Dart to read that state using, say, a Timer. If the state has changed from the last time it was polled, create an event, add to a stream, call a callback, etc etc. If you really want to post an event from a different C thread you need to get into a whole realm of 'ports' which normally isn't worth the trouble.

Comment: the code (understandably) becomes very verbose quickly, finally I would suggest including your last comment above also in your answer as well as it is an important info, thank you.